# Same interface object handle ( slicing and pimpl )

Tags: c++

i want to create a small set of classes to encapsulate HTML content.
For instance i need something like this:

```
struct Document
{
  ...
  std::string content;

  Document& operator<<(Element const& elem)
  {
     content += elem();
    return *this;
  }
};
```

and for example:

```
struct Href
{
 ...
  std::string operator()() const
  {
    return "<a>example</a>";
  }
}
```

and

```
struct Div
{
 ...
  std::string operator()() const
  {
    return "<div></div>";
  }
}
```

I know about pimpl idiom - and about object sliceing.
But is there a way to create somethink similar to archive this:

```
...
Document doc;
doc << Href << Div;
```

Or am i misunderstood something ?

Comment: Either have the elements inherit from a common `Element` base class, and have the `operator()` function pure virtual. Or you can use templates for the `operator<<` function.

Comment: yes, but isn't this only possible if i use pointers to the element ?

Comment: Ah yes that's true. Think it's time to sleep or something now. :) So templates it is the, :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, ok, if you create an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or am i misunderstood something ?

Well, your stream-oriented approach doesn't represent a hierarchical document like HTML (which in its newer forms can be an XML dialect) at all; how would you model, let's say, a link inside a div, and one after a div?

I don't see how the pimpl idiom applies here; it doesn't help you put a hierarchical format into linear shape. You have some approaches here; for example, you could overload the `()` for a arguments that are of a base type to your HTML element classes to implement a hierarchy, but that's besides the point of your question:

You're already breaking it by by defining operators that actually contain what the detail class ("impl") should be doing.

Pimpl forces you to more clearly divide between API and functionality; that's nothing that helps you with a document generator.